# Where statement will not recognize the form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to add records from a query to a table. I am using a form to enter the criteria to add the records.

The where statement will not recognize the form.  I've checked the spelling and confirmed they all match fields I am using.

```
Dim dbs As Database
Dim MSG As String
Set dbs = OpenDatabase("test.accdb")
    dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_Order(fld_ClientId, Fld_orderDate, fld_Route, fld_MealType, fld_order)" _
    & "SELECT fld_clientID, Fld_LastDate, fld_Route, fld_MealType, fld_tueOrder " & "FROM [qry_mealSched]" _
    & "where Fld_Route = Screen.ActiveForm!CMD_Route;"
        dbs.Close
```

When I remove the where statement the code inserts records I don't want.

I tried to spell it all out with this: `where Fld_Route = forms(frm_mealSched)![CMD_Route];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the where clause in this way:

```
& "WHERE Fld_Route = '" & Screen.ActiveForm!CMD_Route & "';"
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  It only took my 4 years to log back in and see your answer.  :)  But I got there